# Why am i getting "undefined"

Tags: function, button, undefined

I dont understand why this is coming out as undefined

I have tried multiple ways of getting the values of each each variable and once i got the "value of null" error to go away, this is my issue.

```html
<form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
  Principal: <br>
  <input type="text" name="principal" value="" id="prin"> <br>

  Amount of Payments:<br>
  <input type="text" name="payments" value="" id="payment"> <br>

  Interest Rate: <br>
  <input type="text" name="interest" value="" id="rate">

</form>
<br>
<button type="button" name="button" id="submit" onclick="interestTot()">Calculate</button>

<div id="div1">

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
let principal = document.querySelector("#principal");
let payment = document.querySelector("#payment");
let rate = document.querySelector("#rate");
let interest ;


if (document.querySelector("#principal)" != null) {
  principal = parseInt(document.querySelector('#principal').value);
};

if (document.querySelector("#payment") != null) {
  payment = parseInt(document.querySelector('#payment').value);
};

if (document.querySelector("#rate") != null) {
  rate = parseInt(document.querySelector('#rate').value);
};


function interestTot() {
  if (principal > 0) {
      interest = rate / payment;

  }
document.querySelector("#div1").innerHTML= interest
};
```

Comment: `document.querySelector("#principal" != null)` evaluates to `document.querySelector(true)`, which is probably not what you want. Also, what's the point of assigning a bunch of fields to variables, only then to not use the variables and assign integer values to them?

Comment: sorry i just noticed that i had the first closing parentheses in the wrong place. i fixed that, but same result. i had to use the if statements so that i could check if the inputs had values because of the "Cannot read property 'value' of null" error

Comment: All I get is script error when trying to run the snippet (loading your code into a snippet)

Comment: when i click the button, instead of getting the result i get "undefined" in div1